# Why is the occupation of harmonic oscillator the Bose function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Is there an intuitive reason why the occupation for the harmonic oscillator is the Bose distribution? I know that a QM-oscillator with commutation relations is a bosonic system but I have no intuition what the quadratic potential has to do with it. Is it just because it gives us equally spaced energy states or does it come from QFT where we treat a bosonic field as a collection of HO‘s at each point?